# How to count and get distrubtion of struct element in array field mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hello I'm working with collection MongoDB contain millions of documents each document contains:

```
       {
"_id" : NumberLong(566994152),
"data" : [ 
    {
        "key" : "der.0",
        "value" : "Ision"
    }, 
    {
        "key" : "d_ont",
        "value" : "Co_OT"
    }, 
    {
        "key" : "ol.tx",
        "value" : "3.35"
    }
    .
    .
    .
    . 

],
"conclusion" : [ 
    {
        "rname" : "O",
        "rulename" : "FTNT"
    }
]
     }
```

My goal is to filter this collection based on a name of a key for example `key="d_ont"` the result is the number of different value of this key and the distribution of each value. for example for the key `"d_ont"` there is 3 value: `"value1"` `50` times `"value2"` `56` times and `"value3"` One time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    },
    {
        $match: { "data.key": "d_ont" }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$data.value",
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

`$unwind` will transform every element of `data` into a separate document. Then you can use `$match` to apply your filtering condition and `$group` to get counts per value (distribution)